# How to convert to int and then compare in linq query c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<classB> list = getItems();
//dt is datatable

list = list.Where(x => Convert.ToInt32( !dt.Columns["Id"]) == (x.Id));
```

I want to only keep the items in the list which match in datatable id column. The rest are removed. I m not doing it right.

The datatable can have: ID - 1,3,4,5,7
The list can have: ID - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I want the output list to have: ID - 1,3,4,5,7

Comment: `!dt.Columns["Id"]` What is this supposed to return that can be parsed into an integer?

Comment: I suspect that all you need to do is remove the `!`...

Comment: I suspect dt.Columns returns a Column collection not a value collection or a single value!

Comment: I have updated above with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
var idList = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(d => (int) d["Id"]).ToList();
list = list.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.Id));
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code won't work because you're comparing a definition of a column to an integer value.  That's not a sensible comparison to make.

What you can do is put all of the values from the data table into a collection that can be effectively searched and then get all of the items in the list that are also in that collection:

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row.Field<int>("Id"));
list = list.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id));
```

Comment: Yes, `HashSet` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that. Your dt.Columns["Id"] returns the DataColumn and not the value inside that column in a specific datarow. You need to make a join between two linq query, the first one you already have, the other you need to get from the DataTable.

```
var queryDt = (from dtRow in dt
              where !dtRow.IsNull("Id")
              select int.Parse(dtRow["Id"])).ToList();
```

Now the join

```
var qry = from nonNull in queryDt 
          join existing in list on nonNull equals list.id
```